# R: How to enclose each element of a string with inverted commas

Tags: r, regex, gsub, stringr

I want to remove blanks, periods and hyphens from a string and enclose each element of the resulting string by inverted commas. Furthermore, I'd like to ensure that all letters are uppercase.

I know how to remove a list of special characters but I cannot add enclosing inverted commas due to my lack of experience with regular expressions or other string manipulation functions (e.g., stringr functions).

How can I convert a string such as

```
test1 <- "A.1, b-1, C"             # start string
test2 <- gsub("[ .-]", "", test1)  # remove period and hyphen
```

to generate the string `'A1','B1','C'`?

Comment: what exactly do you mean by inverted commas?

Comment: Inverted comma or equivalently single quotation mark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `strsplit` on `,` followed by zero or more spaces after removing the `.-` with `gsub` and converting the case to upper case

```
strsplit(gsub("[.-]", "", toupper(test1)), ",\\s*")[[1]]
#[1] "A1" "B1" "C"
```

---

If we need a single string, after removing the `.`, and `-`, capture the word (`\\w+`) and replace it by wrapping the `'` around the backreference (`\\1`) of the captured group

```
gsub('(\\w+)', "'\\1'", gsub("[.-]+", "", toupper(test1)))
#[1] "'A1', 'B1', 'C'"
```

Comment: Your second solution is what I was looking for, thanks. In my implementation in my real life example, I additionally added the blank to the list of characters to be replaced `gsub('(\\w+)', "G'\\1'", gsub("[ .-]+", "", toupper(test1)))`.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
test1 <- "A.1, b-1, C"
test2 <- gsub("[^,\\w]+", "", test1, perl=TRUE)
test2 <- paste0("'", gsub(",", "','", toupper(test2)), "'")
```

Remove all non-word characters other than commas with `gsub("[^,\\w]+", "", test1, perl=TRUE)` and then replace all commas with commas inside quotes and wrap with quotes using `paste0("'", gsub(",", "','", toupper(test2)), "'")`.

Comment: Your solution works fine, thanks. I, however, marked akrun's answer as the "correct one", because it give me more flexibility to handle both sides of each element separately.

Comment: @MatSchu  I am glad you found it useful, +1 for a good question.